# Could not execute method of the activity, When button and textfields are in different fragments

Tags: button, android-activity, onclick, fragment

I have three Fragments and I have textfields in the first Fragment and a button in the theerd.

When I set the onClick for the button in the last fragment to use my method that gets the text in the textfields i get this error:

```
"Could not execute method of the activity"
```

EditTexts are initialized like this in the MainActivity.java:

```
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
```

I am getting my text by doing this:

```
Textfield.getText().toString();
```

I assume that i get this error because the textfields is not in the theerd Fragment.

So how can I get my text?

Thanks in advance.

**CODE UPDATE** (Without the bridge between first and third fragment)

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewpager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);

}

public void createPdf(View view)throws Exception{
    Document document=new Document();
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Report");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }

    File gpxfile = new File(root, "Report.pdf");
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(gpxfile));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable tableone = new PdfPTable(1);
    tableone.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell c5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Report"));
    c5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    tableone.addCell(c5);

    document.add(tableone);

    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

    //table 2

    PdfPTable tabletwo = new PdfPTable(2);
    tabletwo.setWidthPercentage(100);

    EditText driver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    EditText customer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);

    tabletwo.addCell("Driver: " + driver.getText().toString());
    tabletwo.addCell("Customer: " + customer.getText().toString());
    tabletwo.addCell("Cell:");
    tabletwo.addCell("County:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Date:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Date of event:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Tank:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Trailer:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Contact:");
    tabletwo.addCell("Trucknumber:");

    document.add(tabletwo);

}

}
```

FragmentOne.java:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one,container,false);
}
}
```

I have a PagerAdapter for swipe between fragments:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0){
    switch (arg0){
        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentThree();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return 3;
}
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here is the xml for the FragmentOne:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#fff">

<TableLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:hint="Chaufför" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText9"
    android:hint="Kund" />

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

FragmentThree just has a button with onClick="createPdf"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the activity like a bridge from your first fragment to the third fragment. And the proper way is use interface: the fragment declare and the Activity implement:

```
public ThirdFragment extends Fragment{

    ThirdFragmentInterface mInterface;

    ...
    public interface ThirdFragmentInterface {
        public String getText();
    }
}
```

In you Activity:

```
public MainActivity extends Activity implements ThirdFragmentInterface {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getText(){
        return Textfield.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

And then in your Fragment you can get the text value:

```
String text = mInterface.getText();
```

Hope this help. ^^

Comment: How is it done if I want to get data from my second fragment as well?

Comment: Totally the same. Create a "getSecondText()" in the interface and implement it in Activity.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. The error occurs in my method CreatePDF() that is located in the MainActivity at this line: 

"tabletwo.addCell("Driver: " + driver.getText().toString());" 

If I move the button in the third fragment to the first I don't get this error.

Comment: Could you pleas provide more code detail so we can help you better.

Comment: You cannot find the view of Fragment in your Activity. `(EditText driver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);)`
You can write a method in your fragment like 
`public String getText10(){ return txtText10.getText().toString()...}`
And then in Activity call this method with that Fragment instance.
`mFragment1.getText10();`

Comment: In your case, because you use ViewPager, so you need to declare and instantiate Fragment as a variable inside ViewPager. Then in activity you can access that Fragment variable to call that method.

Comment: Ok so now I have added a public string method in my third fragment and when I am trying to use it in my mainactivity its not visible there.

it looks like this:

    public String getDriver(){
    EditText driver = null; 
    return driver.getText().toString();}